# How to control output resistance with voltage

Tags: voltage, resistance

I want to use an LM555 and change the R1 resistance with voltage gradually (staircase waveform). What circuit can i use to change the resistance by changing the voltage?
[image]

Comment: We do not know what R1 is without a schematic. I don't think you can without lots of effort with a digital potentiometer and a circuit to time and control it. Variable resistance components controlled by analog voltages are not linear. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: If you are trying to create a steady load current read this:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_limiting#:~:text=Current%20limiting%20is%20the%20practice,similar%20problem%20in%20the%20load.

Comment: Welcome to the site. People can help you take the next step if your question explains not just your problem but the situation you're in and what you're trying to achieve, too. Please edit your question and greatly improve it, showing your route taken so far in considerable detail with a schematic. The schematic tool here is easy to use. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a very warm welcome.

Comment: Thanks i added the LM555 schematic . I want to be able to control that R1 electronically to ultimately control the frequency of the LM555 output.

Answer (score 1):

There are digital potentiometer ICs available that you could use in place of R1. You have to communicate with them using a micro-controller or other device however. Here is one example:

https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Microchip-Technology/MCP4132-103E-P?qs=hH%252BOa0VZEiBueXVavvhYaw%3D%3D&gclid=EAIaIQobChMInJrjj7jh6gIVjJ-zCh1IrQoVEAQYASABEgLkdfD_BwE

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are creating a Voltage Controlled Oscillator (VCO) with a 555.

[Here is a guide for just such a project.](https://www.electroschematics.com/wide-frequency-range-555-vco/).

Answer (score 0):

you only really need to change the current thart flows through R1s location, so there's many options. here's four of them

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmIj1Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

They'll akll give slightly different performance and with the exception of the second they all give the effect of lower resistance with lower voltage on "in". option 4 will give the best repeatability.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUsQIV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The FF is to give a 50% duty cycle output (at half the frequency).

But you can make a good VCO without the 555 at all.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot change the resistance of a resistor. Even in AC resistance of a resistor is independent of the frequency of AC.

However what you could do is use a BJT transistor. By applying a varying voltage at the base the collector current changes.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPiPS1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With increase in voltage of A , more current will flow through the load and we can say by Ohms law , since the ratio V/I has changed( assuming W is at fixed voltage) resistance has been changed ,more precisely it has been decreased.

The point of the arrow is to the ground the transistor is falsely oriented and because my computer is being serviced I just add this note.

If VA >0.65V then to find current in Rb we will write down Ohms law with a voltage drop of 0.65V:Ib=VA-0.65/Rb.

The current through Rl will be k times the current of the base where k is the gain of the BJT and it is unique for every transistor.

Comment: Thank you! Can you tell me how i can calculate RL in relation to the input voltage at A that i will be changing?

Comment: *"You cannot change the resistance of a resistor"* You can with an digital potentiometer, depending on the current required through the pot.

Comment: Mpessy I will add it to the answer.

Comment: Hmm Mpessy the transistor is falsely oriented. The arrow must point to the ground.